# how to load local data in tensorlayer

Tags: python, deep-learning, load, tensorlayer

How would I change this code which loads cifar10dataset for tensorlayer:

```
# The data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
    self.x_train, self.y_train, self.x_test, self.y_test = tl.files.load_cifar10_dataset(shape=(-1, 32, 32, 3), plotable=False)
```

to load local files with 780x780 pixels and RGB

Answer (score 0):

TensorLayer provides an API to load local data

```
# load a list of PNG image files name
train_img_list = tl.files.load_file_list(path="image_folder", regx='.*.png', printable=False)
# read all images
images = tl.vis.read_images(train_img_list, path="image_folder", n_threads=32)
```

After that, you can use the tl.prepro toolbox to resize all images as needed. http://tensorlayer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/prepro.html

ref:

[SRGAN main](https://github.com/tensorlayer/srgan/blob/master/main.py)

[tl.vis.read_images](http://tensorlayer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/visualize.html#read-multiple-images)